# Setting year to NSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift3, nscalendar

I have not found something on it yet, so I'm hoping this would help someone else. One thing is what is the max year I can set on NSCalendar? The next thing is how would I set the year, I currently use:`let aMillenia = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 3000, to: Date())` but is there a more way to change `byAdding` and using `bySetting` ?

Comment: Use `NSDateComponents`

Comment: There is also a method `date(bySetting:value:of:)`. But maybe you are looking for `Date.distantFuture` ? And don't use `NSCalendar` in Swift 3. Use native `Calendar`.

Comment: "What is the max year": `Calendar.current.maximumRange(of: .year)`. And you can use `upperBound` of that.

Comment: "But is there more way to change `byAdding` and using `bySetting`" ... I'm unclear what you mean.